# How to save the data for customer custom attribute in magento 2

Tags: magento2.2, custom, customer-account, customer-attribute

I created a custom customer attribute using an install script.

```
$customerSetup -> addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
        'is_mpowersync',
        [
        'label' => 'Is Mpowersync',
        'system' => false,
        'position' => 120,
        'sort_order' =>120,
        'visible' =>  true,
        'type' => 'int',
        'input' => 'select',
        "source" => "\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean",
        'required' => false,
        'default' => '0',
        'group' => 'Account Information',
        ]
        );

    $customerSetup -> getEavConfig() -> getAttribute('customer', 'is_mpowersync')->setData('is_user_defined',1)->setData('is_required',0)->setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit']) -> save();
```

I want to set a value the above created custom attribute programmatically creating the customer.
I tried below 3 methods, but data is not saving.

```
1 . $newcustomer->setData('is_mpowersync','1');

2 . $newcustomer->setCustomAttribute('is_mpowersync',1);

3 . $newcustomer->setIsMpowersync(1);
```

Both method not saving the data, if I save from backend admin customer creation it saving the data for the custom attribute.

**How can I save custom customer attribute in Magento 2 programmatically?**

Comment: You may try Magento 2 extension attributes https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/attributes.html (Magento 2.2).

Comment: Are you check my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here in this example, I have tried to save custom attribute value using the Controller file in custom extension. To fix this issue, firstly we need to create ‘controller.php’ file at below location.

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\Controller\Index

```
<?php
Namespace Vendor\Extension\Controller\Index;

class Controller extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

protected $customer;

protected $customerFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer
    \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerFactory $customerFactory
)
{
    $this->customer = $customer;
    $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
}

public function execute()
{

    $custom = $this->_customerFactory ->create();
    $custom = $custom->setWebsiteId($helperData->getWebsiteId());
    $custom = $custom->loadByEmail("abc123@xyz.com");
    $custom->setCustomAttributeCode(custom attribute value);   

  // Main code to resolve this issue.
    $customerData = $custom->getDataModel();
    $customerData->setCustomAttribute('custom_attribute code', 'custom attribute value');
    $custom->updateData($customerData);

    $custom->save();
}
}
```

[For more refrance click here](https://magecomp.com/blog/fix-issue-saving-custom-customer-attribute-value-programmatically-magento-2/)

**Note :** Above code is not tested. you have to check.

I hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for your answer, i want to set the data during customer create programatically.

Comment: I will get back to you if I found something.

Comment: i tried to load by email and update the attribute value, but still i cannot set the data and save it, but customer created

Comment: thanks, i missed this \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerFactory

Comment: ohhh! it's okay good now it's working. thanks for the appreciation.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still struggling to save a boolean custom registration field value in the db make sure that your form field has a default value for the checkbox : **value="1"**

```
<div class="control">
    <input type="checkbox" checked name="gj_newsletter" id="gj_newsletter" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
    echo __('Subscribe to Newsletter') ?>" class="input-text" autocomplete="off" value="1">
</div>
```